# Left div 200px width, content div the rest?

Tags: css, layout, html, width

```
body {
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 13px;
            }

            #wrapper {
                padding: 1px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            #left {
                width: 200px;
                float: left;
                background: orange;
                position: fixed;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 2px;
            }

            #content {
                float: right;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 2px;
                width: ???;
                background: #F0F0F0;
            }
```

Hello again stackoverflow!
I want to create a simple layout, with a menu width of 200px, and the content div that takes the rest of the width... But how can i do that?

I already searched on google and on other stackoverflow topics, but i couldn't find anything...

Greetings

**Edit:** I tried searching on goolge once again and i found an example of how it should look like:
http://www.thesitewizard.com

But because he has some kinda strange div names i don't know what code he uses for what div...

Comment: How about using percentages ? - left width 20% and content width 75% with 5% gutter in between

Comment: No, that looks strange in different screen widths...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can work with float in combination with margin to achieve your desired result. To get what you want your HTML-structure should look similar to this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">place your content here</div>
    <div id="main">place your content here</div>
</div>
```

The minimum required CSS should look like this:

```
#menu { float: left; width: 200px; }
#main { margin-left: 200px; }
```

I added a [demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uL78h/) to show the results with the help of some background colors.

Comment: `margin-left: auto;` would be in this case the better approach, you don't need to repeat `200px`

Answer (score 1):

What about using `display:table, display:table-row, display:table-cell` elements?

jsFiddle here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x5qYd/9/)

display:table is now supported in all browser, so in 2013 i would use this

Comment: it is outdated, `display: flex;` is the new approach (Nov'15)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
width:100%;
padding-left:200px;
float:right;
```

for the #content and

```
width:200px;
float:left;
padding-left:-200px;
```

for the #left

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody has responded with CSS: [flex](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) at this point

```
display:flex;
```

For a tutorial on all the ways you can use this property, try out [flexbox froggy](http://flexboxfroggy.com/)